# Copy from a file until a certain marker string is found

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write some code which will open `List1.txt` and copy the contents up until it sees the string `'John smith'` to `List2.txt`.

This is what I have so far:

```
F=open('C:\T\list.txt','r').readlines()
B=open('C:\T\list2.txt','w')
BB=open('C:\T\list2.txt','r').readlines()
while BB.readlines() == 'John smith':
    B.writelines(F)
```

Here is an example of what `List1.txt` could contain:

```
Natly molar
Jone rock
marin seena
shan lra
John smith
Barry Bloe
Sara bloe`
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for starters your paths are wrong. change \ to \\ or /

Comment: You're opening list2.txt for write and immediately opening it for read? And then you are reading from it? How is that supposed to work? I would expect the write call to truncate the file so that there is nothing for your read loop to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F=open('C:\T\list1.txt','r')
B=open('C:\T\list2.txt','w')
for l in F: #for each line in list1.txt
    if l.strip() == 'John Smith':  #l includes newline, so strip it
        break
    B.write(l)

F.close()
B.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import takewhile

with open('List1.txt') as fin, open('List2.txt', 'w') as fout:
    lines = takewhile(lambda x : x != 'John smith\n', fin)
    fout.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: FYI, you have a typo:  takewile

Comment: Nice answer, but I'd say that using itertools.takewhile() with a lambda plus two opens in a with statement pretty much outs the OP as having had assistance on his homework.

Comment: @hughdbrown: that's probably why OP accepted jdizzle's answer

Comment: So, `takewhile()` is reading from `fout`? `fin` is not actually used in your code. Say, have you actually tested this code?

Comment: @hughdbrown: no it was intentional, I was wondering what kind of behaviour I'll elicit with this sort of typo.

Comment: @SilentGhost: So you write solutions to homework that the OP cannot submit and you intentionally put bugs in the code?

Comment: @hugh: let's review this again: (1) typo, (2) sarcasm, (3) writing pythonic code for easiest of answer is wrong because some one might not understand it. did I miss anything? Well this anything is not my pint, see ya tomorrow.